# Getting information from inner pipeline in cmdlets

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to create a nested pipeline. Now the cmdlet I am running in this nested pipeline needs to check that if it is running from a nested pipeline or not. It needs to behave a little differently when run from a nested pipeline.

Can anyone help how to determine if the cmdlet is run from a nested pipeline?

I use the following code to create the nested pipeline:

```
Pipeline pipeline = Runspace.DefaultRunspace.CreateNestedPipeline("cmdletName","true")
```

Comment: I sense flawed design.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with @Ansgar Wiechers, I think that you are not necessarily approaching pipelines the "right" way.

PowerShell is designed to use separate cmdlets joined together with the pipeline operator `|` to pass data from one cmdlet to the other. Physically creating a nested pipeline breaks this convention, and will overly complicates things.

PowerShell does have several methods to handle pipelines and how data moves through them (for ex. with Begin, Process, End blocks). Here is a link to a reference article that use: [Grown-Up PowerShell Functions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-posh-dba-grown-up-powershell-functions/). It explains how PowerShell's pipelines work, as well as how to use Begin, Process, End blocks, and how to create cmdlets, and is well worth the read.

--Edit--

I think I better understand what you mean. You are running PowerShell inside a C# program (hence needing to create a nested pipeline).

To see if the pipeline is nested, you can use the [Pipeline.IsNested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.isnested%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Property.

Comment: I am creating a nested pipeline because I want to call one cmdlet from already running cmdlet. So I create a nested pipeline in the same runspace and in this pipeline is the second cmdlet. This cmdlet needs to behave differently when called from another cmdlet.

Comment: No I cannot use pipeline.isNested property because I dont have the name of the pipeline to use this property. I need to check this from within the cmdlet that is run in this nested pipeline. Now functions of this cmdlet will not have the Pipeline variable which was used to create a nested pipeline.